# Which component should DAO take place in MVC pattern?

Tags: architecture

As the title, DAOs should be in model block or separated into another block and interacts directly with model block?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few variations and opinions regarding MVC nowadays that it can be tricky identifying where to place what.  You need to use what works for you and what you find pragmatic.  My preference is to have the `Model` contain the data that the `View` displays and interacts with and the `Controller` may interact with both the `View` and the `Model`.  This is somewhat of a departure from the traditional approach where the `Controller` would interact only with the `Model` and the `Model` interacts with the `View`.  I sometimes find that it isn't worth the effort to have the `Model` provide events and the like to have the `View` be bound to those.  Inevitably your `Model`, `View`, and `Controller` are tightly coupled and typically would not be re-used.  Testing the various bits is still quite a bit easier given that they have been teased apart.

It also depends on where you use the pattern.

For Windows Forms I tend to use MVP with more of a *passive view* and for web front-ends I tend to go with what Martin Fowler calls a *presentation model* or what  is referred to often as a `ViewModel` in a MVVM style.

Given those *"constraints"* I would have the `Controller` interact with either a *repository* or a *read model* and pass the relevant data to the `Model`.  The `Model` would not interact directly with any form of DAO.

Sometimes folks like to think of the `Model` as the *business layer* but I do not subscribe to that idea.

Try thinking about your front-end `Model` as simply representing your `View` state and see how that works for you.  In terms of a web-api the `Model` represents the state that goes across the wire but usually will be the state representation of the front-end anyway.  The `Controller` would use that to perform any relevant functionality.